# Autenticação e autorização do email e senha na tela de login

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate

Eu tenho uma tela de login no qual o email e senha já estão cadastrados no banco, porem eu não estou consigo é logar com esses dados que já estão gravados no banco. Na classe loginBean eu preciso não deixar estática, mas sim de acordo com o que está gravado no banco.

OBS1: TODAS ESSAS CLASSES EU TENHO DUVIDA SE ESTÃO CORRETAS.

OBS2: A VIEW DE CADASTRO DE USUÁRIO ESTA FAZENDO A 'EL' CORRETAMENTE. Tela com controller está gravando no banco normalmente.

Vejam as classes:

Classe de modelo:

```
@Entity
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String nome;
private String email;
private String senha;

getters e setters
```

interface:

```
public interface UsuarioDAO {

public boolean verificarUsuario(Usuario usuario);
```

Classe UsuarioDAOHibernate

```
public class UsuarioDAOHibernate implements UsuarioDAO {

private Session sessao;

@Override
public boolean verificarUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    Query query = sessao.createQuery("from Usuario u where u.email = :email    and u.senha = :senha");
    query.setParameter("email", usuario.getEmail());
    query.setParameter("senha", usuario.getSenha());

    return query != null;
}
```

Classe UsuarioRN:

```
public class UsuarioRN {

private UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO;

public boolean verificar(Usuario usuario) {
    return this.usuarioDAO.verificarUsuario(usuario);
}
```

Classe LoginBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

private Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

public String login() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    if ("admin@admin".equals(this.usuario.getEmail()) && "123".equals(this.usuario.getSenha())) {
        this.usuario.setEmail(this.usuario.getEmail());

        return "/admin/ConsultaClientes?faces-redirect=true";
    } else {
        usuario.setEmail(null);

        FacesMessage mensagem = new FacesMessage("E-mail/Senha inválidos.");
        mensagem.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        context.addMessage(null, mensagem);

        return null;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Não é só trocar o if por  "if(usuarioDAO.verificarUsuario(this.usuario))" ?
Este teu "this.usuario.setEmail(this.usuario.getEmail());" não faz sentido para mim.

Comment: Não, porque usuarioDAO é uma interface e não tem como instanciar.

Comment: você deve ter um atributo assim: 
private UsuarioDAO  usuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAOHibernate ();